# python script for cisco traceroute - dont see the entire hops

Tags: cisco

trying to run python traceroute script
trace stuck after 5-7 hops (not 30 as should be).
attached my script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from auto_encrypter_new import *

ios = {
        'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
        'ip': 'my_ip_device',
        'username': user_encrypt,
        'password': passwd_encrypt,
}

net_connect = ConnectHandler(**ios)
output = net_connect.send_command_timing('trace dest_ip')
print (output)
```

get only 6 hops 
while doing this via our router i get more hops 
any suggestion why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this might be due to the timeout issue. Try:

```
output = net_connect.send_command_timing(f'trace {dest_ip}', delay_factor=4)
```

delay factor is explained [here](https://pynet.twb-tech.com/blog/automation/netmiko-what-is-done.html)

if it still doesn't work try:

```
import time
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from auto_encrypter_new import *

ios = {
        'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
        'ip': 'my_ip_device',
        'username': user_encrypt,
        'password': passwd_encrypt,
}

net_connect = ConnectHandler(**ios)
dest_ip = '8.8.8.8'


net_connect.write_channel(f'trace {dest_ip}')
time.sleep(10) # this is needed for the device to send a response. Test it and try to adjust timing if needed
output = net_connect.read_channel()
print(output)
```